# Can I configure webapi to always stream data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an api with many endpoints that produce lazy `IEnumerable` that I would like to stream. By default webapi will buffer the entire dataset. I have written some coontrollers using `PushStreamContent` but it feels like I'm doing something wrong having many end points that look like this::

```
[HttpGet,Route("someaction/{id}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoSomeAction(int id,CancellationToken token)
{
    var data = await GetDataIterator(id);
    if(data == null) return await BadRequest(...).ExecuteAsync(token);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var formatter = Configuration.Formatters.First();
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, transport) =>
    {
            await typeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(data.GetType(), data, stream,
                content, transport, token);
            stream.Close();
    }, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

While I see that if I set Content to a `Stream` it will work, but how do I make this the default behavior for a controller in general so that I don't have to keep writing the same shell?